# Fill pdf with xfdf data

Tags: php, pdf, xfdf

I have some xfdf data as shown here and i need to fill an editable pdf in PHP. Can anyone give me a solution ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
<fields>
<field name="first_name">
<value>tismon</value>
</field>
<field name="last_name">
<value>varghese</value>
</field>
</fields>
<ids original="dbd3aadc6b6b85761ca83030e0558363" modified="1362548354" />
<f href="unlocked.pdf" />
</xfdf>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Download  [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)
2. In case you need to know how to create fdf file through PHP

`$fdf='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
    <fields>
    <field name="first_name">
    <value>tismon</value>
    </field>
    <field name="last_name">
    <value>varghese</value>
    </field>
    </fields>
    <ids original="dbd3aadc6b6b85761ca83030e0558363" modified="1362548354" />
    <f href="unlocked.pdf" />
    </xfdf>';
    file_put_contents("file_name.fdf", $fdf);`

3.Fill FDF to PDF

```
passthru("pdftk fillablePDF.pdf fill_form file_name.fdf output output.pdf flatten");
```

or you do this

```
exec("$root/resources\PDFtk\bin\pdftk fillablePDF.pdf fill_form   file_name.fdf output output.pdf flatten 2>&1");
```

Note: to make the file output fillable, you just ignore "flatten" in both cases:
     `exec("$root/resources\PDFtk\bin\pdftk fillablePDF.pdf fill_form file_name.fdf output output.pdf 2>&1");`

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find a good answer for this as well, and this is the best I've found so far. Seems to work well.

[Merge FDF data into a PDF file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389964/merge-fdf-data-into-a-pdf-file-using-php)